# How to find the direct children (not the children of children) of a div in html using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Markup :

```
<div class = "parent-div">
    <div class = "child-1">
        <div class = "child-1.1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "child-2">
        <div class = "child-2.1">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get a list of the direct children of the div[parent-div]

i.e. a list as:

```
[div class = "child-1">
        <div class = "child-1.1">
        </div>
    </div>,<div class = "child-2">
        <div class = "child-2.1">
        </div>
    </div>]
```

I am using below BeautifulSoup code:

```
page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")
main_cont = page_soup.find('div',{'class':'parent-div'}).findAll('div')
```

This code gives me the list of all divs:

```
[<div class = "child-1">
        <div class = "child-1.1">
        </div>
    </div>,<div class = "child-1.1">
        </div>,<div class = "child-2">
        <div class = "child-2.1">
        </div>
    </div>,<div class = "child-2.1">
        </div>]
```

How do i get a list of just the immediate children of the parent div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `findChildren()` method for getting children tags .

```
main_cont = soup.find('div',{'class':'parent-div'}).findChildren('div',recursive=False)
```

Output :

```
[<div class="child-1"><div class="child-1.1"></div></div>, <div class="child-2"><div class="child-2.1"> </div></div>]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selectors to do this quite easily. NOTE: using Beautiful Soup 4.7+. Specifically, using the child combinator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class = "parent-div">
    <div class = "child-1">
        <div class = "child-1.1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "child-2">
        <div class = "child-2.1">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print(soup.select('div.parent-div > *'))
```

Output

```
[<div class="child-1">\n<div class="child-1.1">\n</div>\n</div>, <div class="child-2">\n<div class="child-2.1">\n</div>\n</div>]
```